# Difference between performing Fard and Sunnah prayer

Tags: sunnah, fard

A four rakaat fard prayer consists of:

- Takbeer, sana
- Two times Fatiha and a Surah
- Atehyat
- Two more times Fatiha (without aayah)
- Atehyaat, Durood and prayer (Rab-ee-Jaalnee...)

Is there any difference when performing sunnah prayers or nafils?

Is durood also included in sunnah? and are last two rakaats read with only Surah Fatiha or an aayah needs to be recited after Fatiha during sunnah?

Are there any other differences between performing sunnah and fard prayers?

Answer (score 2):

The only difference in the prayer is the intention (niyyat).

When praying fard, your intention should be for fard prayer.

When praying non-fard prayer i.e. Sunnah/nafl, your intention should be for non-fard prayer.

Besides this, the way you pray is the same for all.

Answer (score 2):

In Fard nimaz (in case of 4 rakkats) in first two rakkats,at least three Verses from Holy Quran (Ayat) will be recited after Surah Fateha and in the rest of two just Surah Fate ha will be recited.
Whereas in Sunnah/Nafal Prayers,in all four rakats,after Fateha ,any surah from Holy Quran (min.three Ayat) will be recited.
Allah hum sub ko Nimaz ki pabandi atta farmai(ameen)

Answer (score 0):

At the basic level (Arkan) there is no difference between Fard and Sunnah except that in fard you are not required to recite ayah or so of Qura'n after Fatiha. I'm not sure what do you mean by *Durood and prayer (Rab-ee-Jaalnee...)*. as after Atehyaat to saying (Al shahadatyn) is a must. Whatever between that and (tasleem) is sunnah for both Fard and Sunnah prayer.

Answer (score -2):

The difference is just the intention of a person